# PHP $_POST with array and [ ] in key

Tags: php, arrays, encoding

I have a problem when uploading a list of filenames to php. If the filename contains ] it will break the array decoding in PHP.

It can also be reproduced using $_GET as shown here.

What i want this to be decoded as is:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b[]] => c
        )

)
```

The goal is having a key in an array also containing the ] character

index.php?a[b[]]=c

Gives me this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b[] => c
        )

)
```

Encoding them gives same problem

index.php?a[b%5B%5D]=c

Gives me this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b[] => c
        )

)
```

Double encode it does not work either
index.php?a[b%255B%255D]=c

Gives me this:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b%5B%5D] => c
        )

)
```

Is it possible to encode this so PHP will decode it into a array with keys with the string that contains

Comment: Why are you using $_GET?

Comment: Can you show exactly what you want as output - in the same way you are showing what you already get?

Comment: @OsamaIbrahim — See the title and second paragraph of the question. POST and GET have the same problem but GET is easier to construct test cases with.

Comment: If you are uploading a list of filenames, why is the name going in the key and not the value?

Comment: Updatet question with what i want to get. I have the name in the key because i also upload some info per file. I have multiple workarounds, but i am wondering if it is even possible to have ] as a char in a key during upload to PHP

Comment: Why not ask PHP to show you how it should be encoded?

Comment: Try serializing your array using `serialize()` before upload and `unserialize()` it for processing.

Comment: Why does your key need to contain the `[` (or `]`) character(s)? It looks like a wheel, it smells like a wheel, it sounds like a wheel, it *feels* like a wheel, but you want it to *not be a wheel*? So why not just use a "cube"?

Comment: When uploading the list simply strip unneeded characters from the filename or do not use the filename as a key reference at all. I think you're making the world unnessecarily complex for yourself.

Comment: If you're not requiring the *value* of the key, only the *unique identifier* then you can `md5()` the key or even use `base64_encode` (and `_decode` if you need the *value*).

Comment: Please show your code to generate your `var_dumps`  on your question

Comment: None of these answers make any sense. The bracket is a *reserved* character that cannot be used in URL's as you are trying to use it without encoding it on the *client* side first. You are using unsafe characters in a URL and placing the problem on the wrong side. Please read this: https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/

Answer (score 2):

Referencing my comment. You've put your focus on the wrong side of the table. It's not the handling of incoming information that is the problem, it's your client side submission of the data that isn't correctly passing through data. The brackets are ***UNSAFE*** characters to submit through to an endpoint and the client that is submitting this information is where you need to make the changes, not the backend handling the data.

Read up on the safe and unsafe characters in URL's here:

**[Stop using unsafe characters in URL's](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/)**

Brackets are used to define nested list data and the way you are attempting to use it breaks that logic, you will have to change the way your frontend (or whatever is doing the HTTP request) encodes that data.

[image]

Comment: This simply suggests that if you must use *unsafe characters* that they be encoded. OPs post was asking how to properly encode the string so that the browser can properly pass it to PHP and have PHP decode it properly for use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your file upload and you need [ - character in filename or not, but problem with the $_GET array I can sloved so:

```
<? dump($_GET['a']); // Array([b[] => c)
$arr = [];
foreach ($_GET['a'] as $key => &$value) {
    $vl = str_replace('[', '', $key);
    dump($key); // b[
    dump($vl); // b
    $arr[$vl] = $value;
}
dump($arr); // Array([b] => c)
?>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: well this does not work, i can replace away the ] chars in client side if i want. As i commented above i have workarounds, double encode and decode, serialize and deserialize. what i am wondering is if this is even possible

Answer (score -2):

If you write a small script, you can ask PHP what it prefers:

```
<?php
$c = 0;
$data = array(
    "a" => array(
        "b[]" => $c
    )
);
echo "<pre>";
var_export($data);
echo "\r\na[b[]]=c Encoded: " . urlencode("a[b[]]=c");
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**Results**

```
array (
  'a' => 
  array (
    'b[]' => 0,
  ),
)
a[b[]]=c Encoded: a%5Bb%5B%5D%5D%3Dc
```

**Update**

I wrote the following code just to see how the browser is encoding it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("form").submit(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var data = $(this).serialize();
                    console.log(data);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="GET">
            <label for "a">a[b[]] = </label>
            <input type="text" name="a[b[]]" id="a" value="c" />
            <br />
            <button type="submit">
                Go
            </button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I click `Go`, I see the following in console:

```
a%5Bb%5B%5D%5D=c
```

When I then run it through `urldecode()`:

```
<?php
echo urldecode("a%5Bb%5B%5D%5D=c");
?>
```

I see the following results:

```
a[b[]]=c
```

So it looks like you do not need to encode the `=` symbol, but you do want to encode `[` and `]` properly: `%5B` and `%5D` respectively.

So if you want to use:

```
index.php?a[b[]]=c
```

I would advise:

```
index.php?a%5Bb%5B%5D%5D=c
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is just urlencode what i wrote and it will give you exactly the same problem

Comment: @klundby then I would advise providing a more complete example. How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This isn't "asking PHP" anything nor is it an answer.